# blazor webassembly download file from api GET when api requre JWT token?

Tags: c#, download, jwt, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Webassembly ASP.NET Core hosted app, on the server I have a controler that returns a File, and on the Client I would like to have a button that when the user clicks on it download the file, How Can I achive this? when this api uses JWT ?

so api startup add jwt and requre authenticated user always.

```cs
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{      
    options.Authority = appSettings.OcasSettings.Authority!;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
   var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
})
```

now files controller

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]

[ApiController]
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetSdwanFormXLSX/{name}/{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetSdwanFormXLSX(string name,int int)
    {
     ....
      return File().....;
    }
```

and now in Client webassembly

```cs
 private  void ExportToXlsx()
 {
     string ulr = string.Format("api/files/GetSdwanFormXLSX/{0}/{1}", "File1", id.ToString());
     _navigationManager.NavigateTo(ulr, true);
 }
```

But this download / ExportToXlsx()
It open url as it should, but it not pases JWT TOKEN to this  so api instead of returning file it ask for user/pass...

i known that i can `[AllowAnonymouse]` on that controller
but i do not want that - i want to only authenticated users be able to download this files

How to fix that? so this get also pass this api token?

Thanks and regards !